# Fetch unseen mails with python vom Gmail

Tags: python, gmail-imap, imaplib

with the python script below I try to fetch mails from gmail. Im my mailbox is only one unread message, but the script gives me the following output:

> > [b'330 332 335 337 339 340 341 ...... 450]

With an other provider an one unread Mail I get the output:

> > [b'13320]

And that's what I would expect.

Can someone help me, why does gmail print so many unseen mails? (No I haven't received about 80 mails in the last minutes.)

Thanks in advance!

Greetings Jan

```html
import imaplib
from pprint import pprint
i=imaplib.IMAP4_SSL("imap.gmail.com")
i.login("myMailAdress@gmail.com", "myPasswd")
i.select("INBOX")
result, data=i.uid("SEARCH", "UNSEEN")
print(data)
```

Comment: Do you have a whole conversation unread in gmail?  IMAP shows individual messages, not collapsed conversations like the web UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shame on me! Max was right. Thats really embarrassing :-/

I dont'know why gmail doesn't show conversions with unread mails as unread.
On the left side of the web UI it just shows *Inbox (1)*. When I changed the View to 'unseen first' I could see all the unread mails and it says *Inbox (87)*.
Even if I have the Standard-View activated I would expect that gmail shows me the right number of unread messages.

So as you can see, gmail is not my main-mailbox. I've learned a lot in the last days...
Thank you Max and abielita for helping me!!!

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Users.messages: list`](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list) to list the messages in the user's mailbox. Here's an [example](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#examples). Also, refer from this tutorial: [Extract emails from Gmail with Python via IMAP](http://www.voidynullness.net/blog/2013/07/25/gmail-email-with-python-via-imap/).

> For example, to get a list of mailboxes on the server, we can call list():
>
> ```
> rv, mailboxes = M.list()
> if rv == 'OK':
>     print "Mailboxes:"
>     print mailboxes
> ```
>
> A complete version of the above code is available [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/robulouski/7441883).